# PHP Add Leading Zeros based on query array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add leading zeros to all skus in my table. I need every sku to have a 3 digit number in front of it. For 1-9 skus would be 001$row['sku'], 002$row['sku'], 009$row['sku'], 010$row['sku'], 011$row['sku'],...etc  I am using $n=sizeof($row).  But every time I echo this out I get 22 skus (which there are about 50) and only returns the first letter of the sku. I don't understand how to fix this, I am trying to build an array from my query to determine how many skus there are in order to add leading zeros. Any help is much appreciated.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp_table WHERE po='ABCD'");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($row); $i<$n; $i++) {
               if ($i < 9) {
                 $Zeros="00";
               }
               elseif ($i < 99) { 
                 $Zeros="0";
                }
               else{
                 $Zeros="";
                }
               $num=$i+1;    
echo   $Zeros.$num. "=" . $row[$i]['sku'] . "`<br />`";
```

Comment: Why don't you do this in SQL, possibly as SQL view? Oh, and please use parametrized queries instead of `mysql_query()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't looping through the resulting data set quite right, or I don't fully understand the situation.

Assuming you want to build a three-digit SKU based on each row's SKU, here's a better way:

```
// query the database
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp_table WHERE po='ABCD'");

$count = 0;

// Loop through every row in the data result set
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){ 
    $count++; // Increment SKU #

    // Build integer SKU based on count of item in order and pad with zeros
    $this_sku = str_pad( $count, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

    // Build onto integer SKU based on row data and pad with zeros
    $this_sku .= str_pad( $row['sku'], 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

    echo "This product SKU is $this_sku<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Good point. I missed the fact that the loop wasn't correct. Probably the reason you were getting 22 skus is because you were looping through the number of columns in the first row.

Comment: When I try using your code I only get "This product SKU is SKU1" "This product SKU is SKU2".  My table has 2 columns, id and SKU. id is auto incremented and sku contains my skus.  I only want to add 001, 002,...010, 011, 012 to all my skus regardless of what id they have. But I need a way to determine how many skus are in the query.

Comment: So, the end result is... 001SKU1, 002SKU2, 003SKU3, etc. ? And that 001, 002, 003, is determined by what order it is in the SQL results set? Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes this is correct.  There are hundreds of orders in my table and each sku needs to be numbered 001-### for each order. If one order has 120 SKUS I need to list them as 001SKU1 thru 120SKU120. If another order has 160skus I need to list as 001SKU1, 002SKU2, 010sku10, 160sku160.

Comment: I see what you mean. I've updated the code accordingly. Let me know if this is closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: Set Sail Media I really do apprecaite your help but I am still not getting the correct results.  Here is part of my result set. Only returns 3 zeros instead of incrementing This product SKU is 000W3636BD
This product SKU is 000W3636BD
This product SKU is 000W2136
This product SKU is 000W3018BD
This product SKU is 000W2136

Comment: My mistake -- just need to add `$count++` after the opening `while()` loop. See updated code :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand the context, but it sounds as though you want to be using the [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) function.

e.g.

```
$num1 = str_pad(1, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // = 001
$num2 = str_pad(10, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // = 010
// etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [str_pad function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php).

example:

```
$num = str_pad($input, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way is use sprintf() http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

```
sprintf(%'0'3d=%d`<br />`, $num, $row[$i]['sku']);
```